# ¿Cómo pasar datos a traves de window.location.href?

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo un formulario de acceso el cual redirige al usuario haciendo uso de window.location.href necesito saber si hay manera de enviar solo el nombre de usuario a la nueva ventana que fue redirigido.

Este es el fragmento de Ajax que redirige al usuario.

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"../php/usuarios.php",
        data:acceso,
        success:function(data){
            if (data !=0) {
            alert("Datos incorrectos");
            location.reload();
            }else{
            alert("Gracias por continuar");
            window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html'+data; //intente concatenar el data
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Algo salio mal");
            return true;    
        }
    });
```

Intente concatenar el data ya que ahí lleva impreso el nombre de usuario pero no entiendo como usarlo en el ticket de usuario (formulario), no importa si debería usarlo como objeto Json o como un simple string el problema es que no entiendo como imprimirlo en el span de la página que sera redirigido.

Y este sería el form en el que necesito se imprima el nombre de usuario (sapn) que pretendo traer desde el ajax.

```
<main>
   <form >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Consulta</legend>
        <span id="usuario">Aqui va el nombre del usuario desde Ajax</span><br><br>

        <textarea maxlength="250" name="d_problema" rows="5" cols="80" class="d_problema" placeholder="¿Como Sucedio?"></textarea>
        <br><br>

        <label class="textC">Datos de contacto</label><br>
        <input type="mail" name="correo" placeholder="Correo de contacto">
        <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="telefono de contacto" maxlength="10" minlength="0">

        <input type="submit" name="registrar" class="s_registrar" value="registrar">

    </fieldset>
    </form> 
    </main>
```

Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres concatenar el dato a un archivo html? Luego no podrás procesar  ese dato. Tampoco entiendo para qué abres otro archivo ¿? Si usas Ajax puedes actualizar el mismo archivo que hizo la llamada al servidor y recibió su respuesta.

Comment: Lo hize pensando en que se podría usar despues, pero ya veo que no. y uso el Ajax para validar los datos del usuario en una BD, si son correctos que lo mande al formulario y es ahí donde necesito mantener el nombre del usuario para seguir usandolo en la nueva pagina(formulario consulta).

Comment: Precisamente, como usas Ajax no tienes que abrir otra página, sino actualizar lo que haga falta en esa misma página donde tienes al Ajax, ¿por qué te quieres complicar con una tercera página?, no entiendo.

Comment: Por que no lo había pensado de esa manera, no llevo mucho de usar Jquery, entonces sobre esa misma actualizo, ¿El metodo .load() me podría funcionar? tambien e visto que esta location.replace() ¿cual me recomendarias?

Comment: Es que no tienes que irte para otra parte , si te fijas hay una parte `succes` en Ajax, lo normal sería desde ahí actualizar esa misma página con lo que sea sin necesidad de marear al usuario abriendo más ventanas o redirigiendo. Incluso si necesitas contenido totalmente nuevo puedes crearlo de forma programática.

Answer (score 1):

Lo qué tú buscas es convertir el objeto `data` a parámetros o query strings, cosa que es muy simple:

```
var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(function (k) {
  return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
}).join('&');
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "../php/usuarios.php",
  data: acceso,
  success: function (data) {
    if (data != 0) {
      alert("Datos incorrectos");
      location.reload();
    } else {
      alert("Gracias por continuar");
      window.location.href = '../html/Usuario-Ticket.html?' + params(data);
    }
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("Algo salio mal");
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar datos a traves de enlaces como  window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html'+data;
puedes hacerlo empleando GET. De la siguiente manera

```
 window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html?data='+data+'&data1='+data1;
```

Comment: igual y esta fuera de lugar pero como podria manipular esos datos en la pagina a la que redireccione?

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Ajax tienes varias opciones. Una es resolver el requerimiento en la misma pagina, luego de obtener los resultados de (success). La otra opcion. Redirect
window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html?data='+data+'&data1='+data1;
te ayuda a pasar los datos en una variable de tipo GET. y en la pagina a la cual te redicccione lo lees asi: print_r($_GET["data"]) y/o $_GET["data1"].

tambien debes prestar atencion en esta linea data:acceso, no se como este definiendo la variable accesso, pero por lo general data se define algo asi, 
data : {'user':user, 'pass': pass}

Answer (score 0):

En la parte del:

```
window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html'+data;
```

Te faltó poner unir el signo "?" para que no se interrumpa el proceso que esta realizando el ajax.

```
window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html'+'?'+data;
```

Espero y te haya ayudado.

Answer (score -1):

como dice yukoso en la parte de

```
window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html'+data;
```

coloca esto

```
window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html'+'?Parametro='+data;
```

No olvides el que nombre del parámetro que recibes debe ser igual. Por ejemplo:

```
/// controlador
public ActionResult DataFicha(string P_idProyecto) 
{ 

}


//javaScript
window.location.href='../html/Usuario-Ticket.html'+'?P_idProyecto='+data;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.